# Oracke Check constarint - 'deferrable state' options

Tags: oracle, check-constraints

I am trying to understand the difference between 'initially deferred' and 'initially immediate' in oracle check constraint.
What I want to achieve is to load all the data including the rows that violates my checks and then display aggregated error logs rather than stopping the load at the first violation.

Answer (score 0):

Deferrability is not mean to be used outside transactions. They work as:

- `NOT DEFERRABLE`: contraints are checked immediately. If one of them fails the SQL statement fails right away. If the script has 3 updates, each one modifying 1000 rows, then there will be 3000 opportunities where constraints will be checked.
- `INITIALLY IMMEDIATE`: constraints are checked at the end of **each** SQL statement, but not in between. If the script has 3 updates, each one modifying 1000 rows, then there will be 3 opportunities where constraints will be checked.
- `INITIALLY DEFERRED`: is similar to the above but all constraint checks are deferred until the end of the **transaction**. If the script has 3 updates, each one modifying 1000 rows, then there will be only 1 opportunity where constraints will be checked (at the commit).

All the examples above, assume the transaction is demarcated by the client app (or tool you are using). In any case, the deferrability will **never** exceed the transaction boundary.

Comment: what is an Insert of say 6000 rows means here? Is it one transaction?

Comment: `not deferrable` constraints may be checked at the end of the statement too, rather than for each row during it. This is necessary to avoid errors when the constraint is temporarily violated during the DML, but valid at the end https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/cncpt/data-integrity.html#GUID-8AA33487-F1D7-4EC8-ADC1-04A4EEF7974B

Comment: @ChrisSaxon It seems that Oracle implements the last two modes, but not the `NOT DEFERRABLE` mode (see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=70ff0f3ce5db9ff0c0ca5209434fb7cf).  PostgreSQL implements all of them (see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=505b18a0b992bd1062bc78acc3bb2cc4).